# Glassfish 3.1.2 - Understanding EJB (MDB) Thread Pools

Tags: ejb-3.0, threadpool, glassfish-3

I have a MDB that receives messages to process a batch (BatchProcessor).  Instead of working on one item in the batch at a time, the BatchProcessor will create a BatchItemProcessor and using a Semaphore will allow a max number of items to be processed concurrently at a time.  The BatchItemProcessors are stateless session beans and injected by the Glassfish container.

We need to send a SOAP message to another service whenever we finish processing a batch item with its status.  The BatchItemProcessor creates/sends a message to a JMS topic.  We have another MDB, StatusSender, which listens for this messages and creates/sends the SOAP messge to the other service.

The problem is that the SOAP messages aren't being sent until all the batch items have been dispatched by the BatchProcessor.

Looking at the logs, the BatchItemProcessors are being created in an EJB thread pool (e.g. name from logs: `__ejb-thread-pool10`) and the BatchProccessor and StatusSender are created in, what I am assuming is, the Glassfish MDB thread pool (e.g. name from log: `p: thread-pool-1; w: 39`).

I am assuming (because I can't find documentation to confirm/deny) that `p: thread-pool-1;` identifies the pool and `w: 39` the actual thread.  If this is true, then the BatchProcessor uses a completely different thread than the StatusSender since the thread identifiers are different (one for BatchProcess and multiple ones for StatusSender).

Which means I'm really confused as to why the BatchProcessor onMessage must complete before the StatusSender onMessage calls can be executed.

Looking at my Glassfish EJB Container/MDB Settings configuration (both default-config and server-config) I have the following (which I believe are defaults):

- Initial and Min Pool Size = 0
- Max Pool Size = 32
- Pool Resize Quantity = 8
- Idle Timeout = 600

If someone call help me with this issue it would be very appreciated.  Also, any recommondations for a good resource (book, website, etc.) would also be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My issue was related to some code logic which was causing the delay of StatusSender onMessage being executed.  However, I would still appreciate any recommendation for a good reference on Glassfish and threads/pools.

Comment: I gave an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175229/where-can-i-configure-the-thread-pool-behind-the-asynchronous-calls-in-java-ee/40507428#40507428