# Where can I configure the thread pool behind the @Asynchronous calls in Java EE 6?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, java-ee-6

I recently learned that I can easily make [any session bean method Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) by simply adding the `@Asynchronous` annotation.

E.g.

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> processPayment(Order order) throws PaymentException {
    ... 
}
```

I know that Java EE 7 added [Concurrency Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/concurrency-utilities002.htm#CIHFBCFH), but in Java EE 6, where is the thread pool configuration of the `@Asyncronous` methods? is there a way to set a timeout? is it a fixed thread pool? a cached one? what is it's priority? Is it configurable somewhere in the container?

Comment: I had no idea that existed.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think timeout could be achieved by invoking [Future.cancel(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) from a method annotated @Timeout. Requires keeping a reference to the Future returned by the async method, Singleton-ejb can be used for this.

```
@Stateless
public class AsyncEjb {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> asyncMethod() {

        ...
        //Check if canceled by timer
        if(sessionContext.wasCancelCalled()) {
            ...
        }
        ...

    }
}

@Singleton
public class SingletonEjb {
    @EJB
    AsyncEjb asyncEjb;

    Future<String> theFuture;

    public void asyncMethod() {

        theFuture = asyncEjb.asyncMethod();

        //Create programatic timer
        long duration = 6000;
        Timer timer =
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(duration, new TimerConfig());

    }

    //Method invoked when timer runs out
    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        theFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Edit (new below):

In glassfish you may configure the ejb-pool by seting below attributes in the admin console

- Initial and Minimum Pool Size
- Maximum Pool Size
- Pool Resize Quantity
- Pool Idle Timeout

see [Tuning the EJB Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abeea.html#abeee)

Comment: Yep, this indeed answers a major part of my question, but I can't help to wonder, how is the thread pool for this implemented. Is it using executors service, what is the pool policy, max threads, min threads, etc. I'm sure there are some requirements from the implementation from the spec, e.g. I hope it's not just creating a new thread for each call to Async but rather using some managed pool...

Comment: I agree this question deserves a more complete answer :) This was just an attempt to solve part of the use-case in a way i could come up with :)

Answer (score 4):

Even though the solution I found was tested only on Java EE 7/GlassFish 4.1, I think that it should work for GlassFish 3.x too.

There's a JIRA [entry](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17735) on java.net where the different settings are listed. As Oracle is going to pull the plug on that site, I'll quote the relevant post here (formatting added):

> The configuration is in domain.xml, for example,
>
> ```
> <ejb-container>
>   <property name="thread-core-pool-size" value="10"></property>
>   <property name="thread-max-pool-size" value="100"></property>
>   <property name="thread-queue-capacity" value="20"></property>
>   <property name="thread-keep-alive-seconds" value="600"</property>
>   <property name="allow-core-thread-timeout" value="false"></property>
>   <property name="prestart-all-core-threads" value="false"></property>
> </ejb-container>
> ```
>
> All of the above properties are optional. Their default values:
>
> ```
> thread-core-pool-size: 16
> thread-max-pool-size: 32
> thread-queue-capacity: Integer.MAX_VALUE
> thread-keep-alive-seconds: 60
> allow-core-thread-timeout: false
> prestart-all-core-threads: false
> ```

Via that thread, I also found a [blog post](http://javamotion.blogspot.de/2013/07/tuning-suspended-asyncresponse-and.html) that explains how the core and max pool size work. Quote of the important point:

> In the past SUN declared correctly: "That is exactly how it is
>   supposed to behave. First the threads grow to coreSize, then the queue
>   is used, then *if* the queue fills up then the number of threads
>   expands from coreSize to maxSize. Hence if you use an unbounded queue
>   the last part never happens. This is all described in the
>   documentation. If you want an unbounded queue but more threads then
>   increase the core size. Otherwise consider whether a bounded queue is
>   more suitable to your needs."